# Deep linking not worked on tap facebook post android

Tags: android, facebook, post, deep-linking

I want to apply deep linking in my android project.I have downloaded Hackbook and Applinkinghowto and i aam able to post message from both app to fb wall but in default facebook app click setting bar on left side got application name and on click that name my application get open but I want that when I tap on my facebook post so my Application must open if my application is install in device otherwise brwoser should open.but in all case browser is opened.I refered this:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/

and used this code

```
   Uri target = getIntent().getData();
if (target != null) {
    // target is the deep-link Uri
} else {
    // launched with no deep-link Uri
}
```

what i am missing?

Comment: I have same issue. Did you resolved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i solved it.check the information which you have filled on fb developers account like pacakge name,app name,hash key etc. and make sure deep linking is enable.you dont need to write code to enable deep linking. Filling correct and full information on developer account is enough for it.

Comment: I did not find such an option